# Android: Firebase Analytics stopped working suddenly when App is live on google play

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using firebase for analytics and it was working fine for almost a year then suddenly it stopped working a week ago so  No one edits a single char in the app code.

[image]

as we can see crashlytics working fine until now but daily active users and retention and Revenue stopped for no reason
but from the Admob dashboard, I have the right numbers like 200K session daily

I tried to track the problem and I got the error :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/142.250.179.170:443
```

and this one :

request URL :

```
https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/i2vpnx/installations/*/authTokens:generate
```

response :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

**Note : I already updated google.service.json file from firebase**

Any suggestion?

Comment: How you resolved the issue?

Comment: I didn't, Actually, the issue was the app is blocked from the country that we are releasing to it.